# JMS solace connection through proxy

Tags: spring-boot, jms, solace

I am connecting to a JMS solace queue with **Spring Boot 2.7.7** with a **com.solace.spring.boot:solace-spring-boot-starter**.

The property setting up the host is:

```
solace:
  jms:
    host: smfs://host:port
    ...
```

How can I set up the connection to go through a proxy (like proxy:8000) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the JavaRTO API supports proxy at this time, in the Java world.

JavaRTO stands for RealTimeOptimisation, which makes no dynamic memory allocation, it's optimised for high performance low latency use case that you find in Finance.

You shouldn't use JavaRTO unless in this use case.

I guess, you'll need to find another connectivity option to connect to Solace PubSub+ (VPN, private link etc...)

Here are links for reference :

- https://solace.community/discussion/573/jms-with-proxy
- https://docs.solace.com/API/API-Developer-Guide/Session-Props-Required.htm?Highlight=jcsmp%20proxy